# Would having a crazy amount of devices connected wirelessly to one router cause bad up/download speeds and poor ping?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I live in a shared house and my live-in landlord is crazy for smart devices (14 Alexas). I think it's something crazy like over 80 devices are connected to one router. I've been experiencing terrible down and upload speeds since he's been adding more and more items, 0.98mps down and over 200 ping as of last test.

Obviously this makes gaming pointless. Just want to confirm this is the case and if there's anything I could do about it

Comment: Offer the neighbours a crate of beer or a couple bucks per month for their wifi password.

Comment: Run a wire from the router to your room instead of using wifi (if possible).

Comment: For that many devices i would have a router that was capable of creating multiple wireless VLAN networks. For security and wireless client connection stability. Create a wireless VLAN and put all your IoT devices on it. All those cheap smart things go there. Then create another wireless VLAN just for your PCs, Mobile phones and tablets, making sure that one was operating on a different channel to the other (to reduce interference). There's a great router that can handle this. It's called the Dream Machine by Unifi. Your landlord might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is caused by the high number of devices connected to that one router. Although if the router can handle 80 devices then it should be a decent one.

It shouldn't be a problem normally but having that much 'Alexa's connected may be the big cause, since home assistant tech nowadays uses so much network traffic sending requests to the server and getting responses back which consumes bandwidth and lowers the performance.

My advice is you use your own router, it's more safe than using a shared one and you'll at least have all the bandwidth and data for yourself.

I hope my answer will help.

Comment: Right. You can put a second router right next to this one, and connect them via ethernet

Answer (score 0):

I would ask for a dedicated wireless router for YOU even if it is connect to the same internet connection.

Obviously the ultimate solution is to get your own internet service independent of theirs.